# Python 3 - WinError 87 when installing new modules

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install new modules in python 3 and when I run `python -m pip install filename` on my win10 machine then I'm getting:

```
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/48/a76be51647d0eb9f10e2a4511bf3ffb8cc1e6b14e9e4fab46173aa79f981/termcolor-1.1.0.tar.gz
    Error [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect while executing command python setup.py egg_info
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

I tried to run PowerShell as an admin but the problem persists. I also tried to run this command in the cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

termcolor is quite old, the [last release 1.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/1.1.0/#history) was in 2011. There is a [report](https://github.com/pytest-dev/py/issues/103) that Python 3.6+ broke termcolor.

My recommendation is to try [console](https://pypi.org/project/console/).

Comment: Thanks! I tried to install scapy and a few other modules and had the same issue.

Comment: @MikeB. If this answered your question please make sure to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't. I tried to install a few other modules and I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 3):

I received the same error message when executing a `pip install numwords2` from the Pycharm console.

I then upgraded pip, using:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

which uninstalled pip-19.1.1 and replaced it with pip-19.3.1.

The next whack at `pip install` worked well.